# Does ImageResizer CopyMetaData plugin copy the "date acquired" information?

Tags: imageresizer

I'm evaluating ImageResizer CopyMetaData plugin and it seems it doesn't copy the "data acquired" meta tag?

[image: image metadata screenshot]

Is there a reason for this property being discarded?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that this is a windows extended file attribute, and not actually image metadata. If you e-mail the file to yourself and the metadata disappears, then there is your answer. If it is retained, it is likely in XMP or another metadata store that CopyMetadata does not support.

Check out the MetadataExtractor library for a way to access this information. The windows API CopyMetadata uses doesn't support reading or writing XMP.